# SQL - SELECT duplicates between IDs, but not show records if duplicates occur for same ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table (simplified from the real table) at the moment:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Name  | Phone |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | Tom   |   123 |
|  1 | Tom   |   123 |
|  1 | Tom   |   123 |
|  2 | Mark  |   321 |
|  2 | Mark  |   321 |
|  3 | Kate  |   321 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

My desired output in the SELECT statement is:

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | Name | Phone |
+----+------+-------+
|  2 | Mark |   321 |
|  3 | Kate |   321 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I want to select duplicates only when they occur between two **different** IDs (like Mark and Kate sharing the same phone number), but not to show any records for IDs that share the same phone number with themselves only (like Tom).

Could someone advise how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please share examples of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to ensure that another record exists that has the same `phone` and a different `id`. We also need `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates in the resultset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, phone
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.phone = t.phone AND t1.id <> t.id
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfomf9A5wRFsTz8ixQs2aE/0)**:

```
| id  | name | phone |
| --- | ---- | ----- |
| 2   | Mark | 321   |
| 3   | Kate | 321   |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, GMB. For some reason, when I run the query in PHPMyAdmin, I am getting the original table back with the only difference that ID 1 was being placed after ID 3. But all six rows are still present. Weird...

Comment: @Mark: this works fine in the db fiddle that I added to my answer... Are you sure that you are running the exact same query?

Comment: I have tried the query one more time right now (copied it from DB fiddle), but PHPMyAdmin is not outputting the same results. Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by phone, name order by id) as seqnum,
             min(id) over (partition by phone) as min_id,
             max(id) over (partition by phone) as max_id
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and min_id <> max_id;
```

Another method uses aggregation and a window function:

```
select phone, name, id
from (select phone, name, id,
             count(*) over (partition by phone) as num_ids
      from t
      group by phone, name, id
     ) pn
where num_ids > 1;
```

Both of these have the advantage over the exists solution (GMB's) that they refer to the "table" only once.  That can be a big advantage if the table is a complex view or query.  If performance is an issue, I would encourage you to test several variants to see which works best.

Answer (score 0):

Can use somewhat a corelated query  with group by and having as below

```
   Select ID, NAME, max(PHONE) From
 (Select * From Table) t group by id, 
          name having
    1= max( 
    case
   When phone in (select phone from 
     table where t.id<>Id) then 1 else 0) 
      end)
```

[image]